# Not possible to create a sparsebundle image on a SMB mounted Volume

Tags: macos, disk-utility, smb, nas, sparsebundle

I'm trying to create a sparse bundle image from Disk Utility directly on my NAS (through a mounted smb volume):

[image: DiskUtil options]

I then get the following error after a few seconds:

[image: Error message]

Creating a sparseimage the same way works perfectly.
I however wanted to go to a sparse bundle as the file is afterwards synchronized with Google Drive and sparsebundle are seen as folders and are then more sync-friendly.

I'm on 10.10.1.

Info about the mounted volume:

[image: Volume info]

Comment: Does your NAS support AFP? If so, try mounting an AFP share and create the sparsebundle there.

Comment: @TraneFrancks Yes my NAS supports AFP. I enabled it, connected through AFP and was able to create the sparsebundle! It seems you can create an answer with this so I can accept it. Didn't know sparsebundle was linked to the AFP protocol. Is it only for creation or will I now have to always connect to this volume through AFP?

Comment: Cheers. Glad to see it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use sparsebundles and Time Machine backups, a NAS must support AFP and one must mount the share using the AFP protocol. AFP supports metadata transport that is not carried via SMB shares. CIF/SMB should be used with Windows-based systems. AFP should be used with Apple systems whenever possible.

While you might be able to create a sparsebundle and use it under SMB, I can see no reason for doing so. When you're using OS X, you're best served by using AFP.

Comment: I went for SMB2 as, from Mavericks on, Apple moved from AFP to SMB. Seems AFP stays there just for old Macs and TimeMachine. You can find this [here](http://www.apple.com/media/us/osx/2013/docs/OSX_Mavericks_Core_Technology_Overview.pdf). _"SMB2 is the new default protocol for sharing files in OS X Mavericks"_

Comment: Interesting. There's certainly a big difference between SMB 1.x and SMB2. Thanks for the link and the up-to-date information.

Comment: Yes, but what is strange is that my NAS is SMB2 compatible, which means SMB2 doesn't support sparsebundle, nor Versions as I have to also mount as AFP to have it enabled on external Volumes. Weird...

Comment: Within the sparsebundle, things should be fine. It's my feeling that if you needed to create the sparsebundle using AFP, you should also also mount the filesystem in the same fashion. The big question here is whether there are bugs in the SMB2 implementation on your NAS. It's worth repeating, though, that if the idea is to do a Time Machine backup, SMB2 is not supported; you need to use AFP for Time Machine.

Comment: Using AFP worked for me to create a sparse bundle image, my WD MyCloud drive does not advertise AFP support, but I use it for TimeMachine backups, and sure enough I was able to use Finder to mount `afp://wdmycloud.local/` and creating the image there worked.

Answer (score 3):

Support for Time Machine has been added to Samba in 2018, in 4.8.0 release:

> ### Time Machine Support with vfs_fruit
>
> Samba can be configured as a Time Machine target for Apple Mac devices
> through the vfs_fruit module. When enabling a share for Time Machine
> support the relevant Avahi records to support discovery will be
> published for installations that have been built against the Avahi
> client library.
>
> Shares can be designated as a Time Machine share with the following
> setting:
>
> 'fruit:time machine = yes'

Check also https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X